# Access last element of unordered_set in C++

Tags: c++, unordered-set

I have created a unordered_set with [2,3,5] and I want to access in FIFO order, how it is possible with unordered_set, tried doing this but getting compilation error.

```
int showFirstUnique() {
    if(unique.empty())
        return -1;
    else{
        unordered_set<int> :: iterator itr=unique.end();
        itr--;
        return *itr;
   }
}
```

Comment: The `unordered` part of `unordered_set` means you can't use that container with any concern for ordering.

Comment: What is the actual problem you need to solve? Why do you need to get some order from an unordered container? Why have you selected to use an unordered set?

Comment: You can't impose an order on an unordered container.  If you need fifo, you need a queue.

Comment: The associative containers like `set` sort their elements by value. You can't use them for a FIFO. Use a sequential container like `vector` or `deque` depending on the use case.

Comment: multiple syntax errors -- unordered_set<int> :: iterator has no spaces as the iterator belongs to the type and is part of the std namespace i.e. `std::unordered_set<int>::iterator `. You also need to `#include <unordered_set>` if you haven't already.

Comment: @kjhf Whitespace is mostly ignored in C++, and this is no different. It looks bad, but is not invalid.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen sorry the point was more towards the namespacing and lack of MCVE, unless OP already has a using namespace std declared. `unique` is also undefined.

Comment: Aside: `showFirstUnique` looking at the `end` of a container?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux sure, if it were named `showLastUnique`

Comment: @Caleth That's fair, but it wasn't clear that this is what your comment was addressing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Access last element of unordered_set in C++

You can access the last element of unordered associative containers the same way as you can access the last element of forward list: By iterating the elements until you reach it.

The asymptotic complexity of doing this is of course linear, and it is not something that one would typically do with an unordered container.

> ```
> itr--;
> ```

This does not work because unordered container iterators are forward iterators. They cannot be iterated backwards.

> I want to access in FIFO order

Elements of **unordered** containers are not stored in FIFO order. The last element of such container has nothing to do with the order in which the elements were inserted.

You can instead use `std::queue` for example to have a FIFO order.

Comment: `std::unoredered_set` has an `end` member function.  Why would you not use that?

Comment: @NathanOliver Because it does not return iterator to the last element. It returns iterator one past the last element.

Comment: So do `auto end = data.end(); end--; *end;`?

Comment: @NathanOliver You cannot use decrement operator with forward iterators.

Comment: Aha.  Not sure why but I thought they were bidirectional.  Makes sense now why there is no rbegin().

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`boost::multi_index`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) to have both unordered lookup and insertion sequence.

```
template<typename T>
using fifo_set = boost::multi_index_container<T, 
  boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
    boost::multi_index::random_access<>,
    boost::multi_index::unordered_unique<boost::multi_index::identity<T>>
  >>;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can get only unique elements in the original order by using two variables - an output container (here `std::queue`) and a helper `std::(unordered_)set`

```
std::vector<int> input {3, 6, 3, 2, 0, 2, 6};
std::queue<int> fifo;
std::unordered_set<int> helper;

for (int i: input) {
    auto [_, wasInserted] = helper.insert(i); //C++17
    if (wasInserted) {
        fifo.push(i);
    }
}

while (!fifo.empty()) {
    std::cout << fifo.front() << " ";
    fifo.pop();
}

//output 3 6 2 0
```

You can use any other container instead of `std::queue` - `std::vector` would work just as well. `std::queue` says to the reader "this container is meant to be used in FIFO mode", which you may or may not want.

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou everyone.

I understood unordered set don't work in ordered way and hence implemented the same with the help of queue.